# Helping solving a variety of errors

Tags: r, dplyr

Hey stackoverflow community,
I'm quite new to coding, actually got into it through my college. I'm studying Psychology and our class got introduced to R as a way of working with statistics. We had a few classes, I typed every line of code down, but somehow now, I'm getting errors that I have no idea how to solve. Please no hate - as I said, I'm quite a newbie right now.

Thanks in advance :)

Here's the whole code:

```
DS <-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dfusocialpsy/teaching/master/data/coda_ue_01.csv")
names(DS)
str(DS)
#How to do boxplot - DS (List) and the "$" sign is for specific variables within the list
boxplot(DS$hoehe_cm)
DS$mps <- DS$distanz_m/DS$zeit_sec
boxplot(mps)
#Round used to round values up, and mean for average of a certain variable. "Na.rm" stands for NA remove as in removing unknown (NA) values.
#If na.rm = TRUE, then unknown values will not be included in average, if na.rm = FALSE, then unknown values will be included. "digits" simply states 
#to which decimal point. 2 = 2 decimal points etc.
round(mean(mps, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
write.csv(DS,
          "my_first_ds.csv",
          row.names = FALSE)

getwd()

ds <- read.csv("coda_05.csv",
               header = TRUE)
View(ds)

dsba <- ds

#Base R 
ds$geb_jahr <- 2021 - ds$alter

#tidyverse 
library(tidyverse)

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(geb_jahr = 2021 - alter)

names(ds) <- c("id", "age", "gen",
               "rwa_01", "rwa_02", "rwa_03", "gb_jahr")

names(ds)[names(ds) == "age"] <- "alter"
names(ds)[names(ds) == "gen"] <- "gender"

ds <- ds %>%
  rename(gen = gender,
         age = alter)

ds$gen_f <- factor(ds$gender,
                   levels = c(1,2),
                   labels = c("w", "m"))

ds$gen_num <- as.numeric(ds$gen_f)

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(gen_f = factor(gender,
                        levels = c(1, 2),
                        labels = c("w", "m")))

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(gen_num = as.numeric(gen_f))

ds$sage_z <- scale(ds$age)

ds$age_cen <- scale(ds$age,
                    scale = FALSE)

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(age_z = scale(age),
         age_cen = scale(age,
                         scale = FALSE))

ds$rwa_02_r <- 6 - ds$rwa_02

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(rwa_02_r = 6 - rwa_02)

#Base R
which(ds$age > 30)

ds$age[which(ds$age > 30)] <- NA

ds$age_ja <- ifelse(ds$age <= 25, 1,2)
ds$age_jma <- ifelse(ds$age <= 20, 1,
                     ifelse(ds$age <= 25, 2,3))

table(ds$age, ds$age_jma)

#tidyverse
ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(
    rwa_di = recode(rwa_01,
                    '0' = 1,
                    '1' = 1,
                    '2' = 1,
                    .default = 2))

### Compute scale values ###

#Base R
ds$rwa_mean <- with(ds, (rwa_01 + rwa_02_r + rwa_03) / 3)

(ds$rwa_01 + ds$rwa_02_r + ds$rwa_03) / 3

ds$rwa_mean <- rowMeans(ds[c("rwa_01", "rwa_02_r",
                             "rwa_03")],
                        na.rm = TRUE)

#tidyverse
ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(rwa_mean_na = (rwa_01 + rwa_02_r + rwa_03) / 3,
         rwa_sum = rowSums(data.frame(rwa_01, rwa_02_r, rwa_03),
                           na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi DorimeDoge, this is a bit of a code dump, and it would help if you could make your code minimally reproducible. That is, target the specific bit of code where you are running into a problem and focus on them.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do you expect to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: Tackle the errors in order. Later errors will likely be solved by fixing previous errors. Run your code one line at a time. Use the console to look at objects as you go and make sure they look right and you understand it (e.g., periodically type `ds` or `View(ds)` in the console to see what `ds` is at that particular step), and stop when you get to the first error. Google the error message, look at the objects that are used in the line that caused the error, and if you need help post the code leading up to and causing that error, including the error message, not 100+ lines of code.